# How we can access hyper link from table td in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink, webdriver

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="sorting_1">Abrar</td>
<td>1571</td>
<td>Out</td>
<td>No</td>
<td>ALL</td>
<td>Deskflex</td>
<td>
<a class="btn" href="/override/OverUserOverRide/21801" style="font-size: 15px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

```
IWebElement t = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*table[@id='customerDatatable']"));
            t.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href='/override/OverUserOverRide/21801']")).Click();
```

I have used this code but not working. [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEjzO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the 1st element **t** locator, since it's not a valid one.

```
//*table[@id='customerDatatable']
```

You should use either * (for searching among all tags) or specific TagName (table in your case), so it could be:

```
//*[@id='customerDatatable']
```

or

```
//table[@id='customerDatatable']
```

Comment: Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href='/override/OverUserOverRide/21801']"}
please check next line issue